# Change url in address bar while being able to refresh back to original url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

So when you change url with history.replaceState method and refresh the page, browser will load the modified url, not the orginal one. 
For example let's say the original link is /admin.php?page=somepage and I change the url to /somepage . When I refresh the page, it will load /somepage but my desired action would be for the browser to load /admin.php?page=somepage . Can I do something like that?
I tried changing the url back on beforeunload, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Hard to make much sense out of what exactly you are trying to do and what or where the specific problem is

Comment: I want to change url in the address bar without reloading. For example the orginal url is /admin./php?page=somepage, I use history.replaceState and change the url to /somepage . When I click refresh button, browsers loads /somepage, but I want the browser to load the orginal url.

Comment: You can't control that if user hits refresh, browser will refresh what is in address bar. What isn't explained is what is going on with these changes you are making and no code has been provided

Comment: Well thanks for explaining. I think the only only way would be to change the address bar again before user hits refresh, which seems hard to do, if not impossible. I wanted to make a js fiddle, but the script seems to be executed from an iframe, and when I'm trying to update address bar like parent.window.history.replaceState, I get blocked by same origin policy: "Blocked a frame with origin "https://fiddle.jshell.net" from accessing a frame with origin "https://jsfiddle.net""

Comment: perhaps you could parse the url on page load and if certain data doesn't exist that relates to your javascript routing you can redirect to another location